# Not able to select currently selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm close but no cigar.

I'm creating a "slide show" with accompanying text.

I'm able to select new photos and text but am missing something simple when it comes to selecting the navDiv which selects the photos/text.

I've created a jsfiddle but in essence its:

```
$('.sectionGraphics').hide(); // Hide the existing photos

$('.sectionNav div').click(function(){

    $('.sectionGraphics:visible').hide(); // Hide current visible section
    var selected = $(this).data('target'); // Show selected section
    $('#slideShow > #'+selected).show();
    $('#test').html(selected).attr('class','').addClass(selected); // Show accompanying text

    //BUT NOW I WANT TO MAKE SELECTED NAV BOX WHITE AND CAN'T SEEM TO SELECT IT

    if (selected=="aaa"){ 
        $('#aaa').attr('class','').css("background-color","white");
    }
    // $('.sectionNav div > .'+selected).css('background-color','white');

}).first().click();
```

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/S63wy/6/

(I didn't upload the photos - but it shouldn't matter - I changed the size to give a visual clue.)

EDIT: Updated my jsfiddle to remove duplicate div names

Comment: You're duplicating IDs which I'm pretty sure won't be helping matters. IDs should be unique. Use classes when you want multiple elements with the same identifier.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. The JS fiddle shows me 3 squares and clicking each square changes the big output square on the right. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: he wants the selected little gray square to become white once is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get the currently clicked element.

I added these two lines:

```
  $('.sectionNav div').css('background-color', '');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gqAH/

The first line removes the background color from all of the div elements, and the second line adds it again to the current element.

I think your code could use a bit of tidying up though, the above is just an example and classes might work better. You have some duplicate ids.

Comment: You can use my JS fiddle for reference, I haven't touched any other code.

Comment: Thanks this did it -- don't know how I messed it up. I will post a finished version in jsfiddle in a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S63wy/5/)

jQuery

```
$(function(){

  $('.sectionGraphics').hide();

  $('.sectionNav div').click(function(){
    var nav=$(this);
    $('.sectionGraphics:visible').hide(); // Hide current visible section
    var selected = $(this).data('target'); // Show selected section
     $('#slideShow > #'+selected).show();
     $('#test').html(selected).attr('class','').addClass(selected); // Show accompanying text
     //WANT TO MAKE SELECTED NAV BOX WHITE
    $('.sectionNav div').removeClass('selected');
      nav.addClass('selected');

   // $('.section_header div > .'+selected).css('background-color','red');
  // $('#slideNav4').css('background-color','red');
   // $('.section_header div > #SN-'+selected).html("aaa");

  }).first().click();


});
```

CSS

```
.on {
    background-color: white
}
.aaa {
    background-color: gray
}
.bbb {
    background-color: red
}
.ccc {
    background-color: blue
}
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.box:hover, .box.selected {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go over all of these to find where I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Within your click handler, `$(this)` will refer to the button (div) that has just been clicked.

*[Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/shai/S63wy/9/) (added lines 13–14 in JS, 21-23 in CSS)*

Added JS:

```
$(".sectionNav div").removeClass("box-selected"); // remove the white from all buttons
$(this).addClass("box-selected");                 // make the clicked button white
```

and added CSS:

```
.box-selected {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will put up my final code in jsfiddle for future reference. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I could not really understand the problem.

If you want to check which small red box was clicked then you can use `$(this)` as in

```
$(this).siblings().each(function(){ $(this).css('background-color','red') });
$(this).css('background-color','white');
```

**$(this).siblings()** bit puts all the backgrounds to red or whatever colour you want. 
Let me know if that was not what you wanted.